# How to remove accelerometer or gravity or whatever this value in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I am making a little game using cocos2d.

Now i want to remove value that is showing on my screen at left-bottom corner.

like this

[image: accelerometer value when using cocos2d]

Comment: lol I really wonder how did you get to the conclusion that it might have been either acceleration or gravity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[Director sharedDirector] setDisplayFPS:NO];
```

It's the frame rate display.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a problem with your acceleration or gravity.. It's a Frame Rate. To remove that frame rate,try like this.

in AppDelegate.m

you can find the line like this..

```
[director setDisplayFPS:YES];
```

change it to:

```
[director setDisplayFPS:NO];
```